# onTouch is not working

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, ontouch

I used processing for draw something. After that exporting for android. So I should use this class. `public class DrawMap extends PApplet implements View.OnTouchListener`
 My problem is I need to detect when someone is touch on the screen 
but this is not working properly.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean touching;

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        touching = false;
    }else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        touching = true;
    }

    float touch_x = event.getX();
    float touch_y = event.getY();

    return true;

}
```

Comment: What problem u getting ?

Comment: Hi. In this class, this Touch function is not working.I could not reach even with debugging . I guess , I should extend a View or activity but I have already one. What I need is to get a point on the screen in that class.

Comment: Check if u are setting listener to view as posted in answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you forget associate each other may not working. This is how you implement a touch listener in Android.

```
    view.setOnTouchListener(this);
```